# How to solve EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for <Entity> was found?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, entity, typeorm

I am working on nestjs with typeorm,
In my app.module.ts I have this (it works):

```js
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
    type: 'postgres',
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    port: parseInt(process.env.DATABASE_PORT),
    username: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
    entities: [User, Candidate, Job, Language, Tool, ActivityArea, Contract, Location],
    synchronize: true,
})
```

During development, I found a better way to include entities on the internet:
`entities: ['./database/entities/**/*.entity.{ts,js}']`
but I got this error : `EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for <Class> was found.`

I also tried this :
`entities: [ __dirname + '/../database/entities/**/*.entity.{ts,js}']`,
`entities: [ __dirname + '/database/entities/**/*.entity.{ts,js}']` and even
`entities: [ './database/entities/users/*.entity.{ts,js}', './database/entities/basicClasses/*.entity.{ts,js}']`
and many other spellings with and without '.entity', '*', '**' and {ts,js}
but none of this works and everything returns the error.

I precise that I use :

```js
seeds: [
    './database/seeds/basicClasses/*{.ts,.js}',
    './database/seeds/*{.ts,.js}'
],
factories: ['src/database/factories/**/*{.ts,.js}']
```

in data-source.ts which is working.
But if I try to do the same thing in data-source for entities, it doesn't work either.

I have @Entity() before the export of each entity.

Here is my tree structure:

```
|database
|-entities
|--users
|--basicClasses
|-data-source.ts
|app.module.ts
```

Can you help me solve this problem please?